# How would you call a life-cycle management class?

Tags: naming-conventions, lifecycle

As an example you can think of a hibernate transaction and a class which begins one for a thread, commits and rollbacks, Or a class which gets a session, closes it and flushes it (both examples are with the threadlocal pattern in mind).

Answer (score 1):

UnitOfWork?

See http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2007/06/08/rhino-commons-repositorylttgt-and-unit-of-work.aspx .

Comment: +1  A classic Fowler PoEAA pattern that I am a big fan of.  http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html